# Feature Request: "I'm At Work" Mode in Chat Rooms

Tags: feature-request, chat

You know what would be a cool chat room feature?

The ability to flip on "I'm at work" mode in the chat room, where no embedded images are shown automatically, but they still show up for people who are not in "I'm at work" mode.

Here at Serverfault, it's expected that most of us are working professionals, and since we come from all over the globe, some of us are always at work when others of us are enjoying a hard drink after a long day on the job.  Even though it can be nice to be able to leave chat open in the background and be able to talk to fellow sysadmins when you want, sometimes we post goofy pictures in chat. Which is fine, I certainly don't want to stop people from posting humorous or even distasteful images if they want... I'd just like the ability to control whether they pop up automatically or not.

Comment: I know there are userscripts that allow you to clear embedded images -- perhaps one of these could be modified by an enterprising soul to convert images to links sutomatically?

Comment: I agree with this - inappropriate images are my favourite bit of chat and agent an issue when I'm in the office. However, when with a customer its a bit awkward to alt-tab to my remote desktop (where  I do most of my surfing) and see a dodgy image.

Comment: @Dan Just tell them your other client is Passion Natural Lubricants and you're hardening their web apps.

Comment: @Wesley I hear they have no problems with penetration testing.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137584/hide-or-collapse-individual-comments-in-chat

Comment: @Iain Great minds think alike?

Answer (score -2):

An alternative (and probably unpopular) way to solve this would be to split "official" chat:

- A shopping/localised/"on-topic" channel (e.g. "What sort of XYZ do I need to talk to my 1970s QRS?")
- An "off-topic" channel for the social stuff

Comment: Can't see this working - what makes chat here so great is its fluid nature and I don't think people will want to monitor multiple rooms. Additionally, most peoples activity is when they're at work anyway